# Celery Task instanciation cache

Tags: python, django, caching, celery

I'm trying to cache a large resource file among tasks using Celery 4.0.2.

Looking it in the documentation , I have reach with the task caching part.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#instantiation

*This can also be useful to cache resources, For example, a base Task class that caches a database connection:*

```
from celery import Task

class DatabaseTask(Task):
    _db = None

    @property
    def db(self):
        if self._db is None:
            self._db = Database.connect()
        return self._db
```

In my case I have done some changes to cache my big file resource, and the object its shared among the tasks,  but the memory used by big file resource are cached in the task forever.

```
from celery import Task

class BigResourceTask(Task):
    _resource = None

    @property
    def resource(self):
        if self._resource is None:
            self._resource = load_big_resource()
        return self._resource
```

How can I free that memory or make it expire after the execution of all the related tasks?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are creating `_resource` on demand after checking if it exists, you can simply delete whenever you want it.

```
# complete all the tasks
del BigResourceTask._resource  # free memory

# do something else

r = BigResourceTask.resource  # create when needed
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay . I have tried this , but this is creating new resources for each process. I was trying to have some kind of shared object for all process with the same base task.